# How to define exact value of Average Purchase Revenue Per User in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, admob

I'm developing a game with advertising monetization. I use Firebase analytics to track ad revenue. But revenue per user (APRU) is less than one cent ($0.01) and it is not displayed on the panel in Firebase (because of $0.01 is the minimum step value). I tried changing the currency from dollar to another one (with lesser value), but I did not find such a setting. [image: APRU panel in Firebase console]

I use the free version of Firebase (web application). Maybe in order to change the currency you need a paid version? Or maybe there is another method of calculating the APRU value for a specific released version of the application?